# sending xml to queue in active MQ using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am sending my object as XML by marshalling it to queue, but it is not submitting to queue nor giving any error:

```java
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RabbitMQConfig.class);
AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContractFullInfoRequest.class);
Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
marshallerObj.marshal(contractFullInfoRequest, sw);
String xml = String.valueOf(sw);
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(imeValidationExchange, imeValidationRouting, xml);
```

Can any one please look into it?

Comment: There is not enough information provided to share any insight. You would need to include the information about how the ConnectionFactory to the ActiveMQ broker is configured and wired into your amqpTemplate. Please share logs, config files, spring files, etc.

Comment: Also, adding `System.out.println()` statements at the different points in the code, or running in the debugger, can help to figure out where it is reaching, and not.  For example, it could be getting stuck on the actual `convertAndSend` call because of trouble getting the connection to the broker.

Comment: `jstack` on the running process could yield good insight as well.